# Conditionally clear activity backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

I am working on an app on which you can share images from your local phone's gallery app. Whenever a photo is shared through the gallery app, an `Activity` `A` opens up in my app.

The photo sharing follows some steps in which it goes from `Activity A` to `Activity B` and the final step in `B` opens the `Main Activity`.

What I want, pressing back from `B` should open `A`. Pressing the final button in `B` should clear both `A` and `B` from backstack, so that if you press back on `Main Activity`, the app should close.

What I did :

1. Initially, I was opening `Main Activity` with this flag `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`
   But, this started a new task and so even when I used to close my app and go to the phone's gallery app, it would show `A` instead of the photo on that app, when you pressed back, then you could see the actual image in that gallery app.
2. I had specified `android:noHistory="true"` for `A` and `B` and started the intent to `Main Activity` without the new task flag. This solved the new task problem in the sense that when I close my app and switched back to the gallery app, it showed the actual image not my activity `A`. But the issue here is, I can't go back to `A` from `B`, also if the app is minimised, then also the activity is gone.

Comment: call finish() when your calling another activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a singleton class :

```
Stack<Activity> stack;

public void add(Activity activity){
   stack.add(activity).
}

public void remove(){
   Activity activity = stack.lastElement();
   if(activity != null) {
      stack.remove(activity).
      activity.finish();
   }
}

public void removeAll() {
   for (Activity activity : stack) {
      if (activity != null)
         activity.finish();
   }
   stack.clear();
}
```

call add() in your activities' onCreate()

call remove will finish current activity 

call removeAll will finish all activities added into the stack

Comment: didn't understand. could you share a snippet explaining this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        l.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        l.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        l.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(l);
```

**use this on finish button in avtivity B.**

Comment: this code works for the case of going back to `A` from `B`. But after the final button in `B` when I go `Main Activity` and close the app, the phone's gallery app still shows `A`.